# Bash script programming

Tags: bash

I want to keep printing in a while loop(this occurs every second , i.e. sleeps for one second) and keep asking for a user input in a separate while loop, however if one indefinite runs , it doesn't go to the other for loop and if we run one in background and one in foreground still it doesnt helps, I am programming in bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

memusageStatus=false
diskspace=false
processStatus=false
menuStatus=true

function printMenu {
while [ true ]
    do

    if  $menuStatus ; then
    printf "\na) Show/Hide Memory Usage Information \nb) Show/Hide Disk Space Information \nc) Show/Hide Process Information\no) Show/Hide List of options \nq) Exit\n"
    fi

    sleep 1
    tput cup 0 0 ;
    tput ed
    done

}
function disMenu {

while [ true ]
do      
    read ab
    echo ab
    case $ab in
        'a') if $memusageStatus ; then
            # free -k 
             memusageStatus=false;
            else
              memusageStatus=true;
            fi
            ;;

        'b')     if $diskspace ; then 
                diskspace=false
             else
                diskspace=true;
             fi
            # df -h 
              ;;
        'c')     if $processStatus ; then 
                processStatus=false
             else
                processStatus=true;
             fi 
            ;; #ps u 
        'o')        echo "you pressed o"
             if $menuStatus ; then
                menuStatus=false;
            else
                menuStatus=true;    
             fi   ;;
        'q') exit 0;;
    esac
done
}
printMenu & 
disMenu
exit 0
```

Comment: Can you also update the question with the sample code ?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Unfortunately, this is not a "give me a program" website. For people to help you, they expect that you have done and shown some amount of research effort and a specific, narrow question.

Comment: no problem, i will upload the code too

Comment: It would be helpful if you could make a [minimum, verifiable, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue, rather than pasting the entirety of your program and asking why it doesn't work

Comment: In `printMenu` you are not breaking out of the loop anywhere, where do you expect it to break?  Are you expecting the background job and the current one to be somehow magically synchronised?  Why do you need two loops anyway?  It is difficult to see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: By the way you don't need the `[` (`test`) command, `while true` or `while :` is sufficient.

Comment: You may also want to pick a better title to attract more people.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a **read -t 1** in only one loop instead of a sleep 1.
But maybe with a longer read time.
Something like:

```
while [ true ]
do
    echo "Show your Menu"
    read -t 5 ab
    case $ab in
        'q') exit;;
    esac
done
```